# How do KTables get their initial values?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've recently been looking into the Kafka Streams API and I'm having a little trouble fulling understanding KTables. I think I understand the general concepts but I'm struggling with a few of the details.

In my example application, I fetch a bunch of prices and then use the Kafka Streaming API to produce average prices for each product to a *compacted* Kafka topic (*Topic-A*). I have a second service that I want to react to these averaged price updates. So in that second service, I create a `KTable` over *Topic-A*, and I can query its store successfully.

My goal is to have this second service process & react to these averaged prices in real-time, but also to have access to the latest value for each product on demand. I believe I can use a KTable and Store to do this.

Initially, I believed:

- The KTable is backed by a local store (RocksDB instance)
- When the KTable is initialized, it consumes the entire of *Topic-A* to build its KTable

However, it seems as though KTables are (or can be?) backed by a [compacted change-log](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide#streams_processor_statestore).

1. **Does this mean that upon initialization, the KTable only needs to consume the latest record for each key?**
2. **If I run multiple instances of my second service do the KTables share a change log?** I imagine if the number of instances was scaled up/down, instances would need to update their local state to account for data from more/less partitions.
3. **Would using a GlobalKTable give me all the K/V pairs available in each instance?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Does this mean that upon initialization, the `KTable` only needs to consume the latest record for each key?

Yep. If data in the underlying topic is such that each value represents a complete latest value for that key, then the topic can be configured with `cleanup.policy=compact` and Kafka Streams only needs to read the latest value to restore the `KTable` (which is a RocksDB store). In terms of data modeling, this is the only kind of data/topic you want/makes sense to use as input for a `KTable`.

> 2. If I run multiple instances of my second service do the `KTables` share a change log?

Yes, they read from the same changelog topic but they generate their own RocksDB stores based on the `state.dir` param you provide in the Kafka Streams configuration.

> 3. Would using a `GlobalKTable` give me all the K/V pairs available in each instance?

Yes, but `GlobalKTables` are slightly more limited in what you can do with them than regular `KTables`. I believe the new 1.0.0 release has added functionality to `GlobalKTables`, but they still have some limitations.

Comment: If a global KTable has every K/V pair available, I can't see an obvious reason why [Confluent's streaming example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/MusicPlaysRestService.java) doesn't use a GlobalKTable, but instead fetches data from other hosts?

Comment: Probably just to demonstrate interactive queries.